# Adding to Multi-Value Lookup Column via PowerShell (SP 2013)

Tags: powershell, lookup-column, multiple-values

Is there any way via PowerShell to *add* data to a multi-value Lookup column instead of overwriting it?

For example, the item already has stuff checked off in the Lookup column. Values 1 and 2 are already checked. But I want to add 3 without overwriting 1 and 2.

Here is a snip of my code:

```
foreach($row in $csvVariable)
{
$updateitem = $list.GetItems($query) | Where {$_["Entity Name"] -eq $row.AccountIdName}

$lookupfield = $list.Fields["Lookup"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookup];
$lookuplist = $webDestination.Lists[[Guid]$lookupfield.LookupList]; 
$sourcefield =  $lookupfield.LookupField;            
$lookupitem = $lookuplist.Items | Where {$_["Title"] -eq $row.new_UpperTierIdName}
$lookupvalue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($lookupitem.ID,$lookupitem.ID.ToString());  

$updateitem["Lookup Column"] = $lookupvalue
$updateitem.Update()
}
```

The csv file is a many-to-many report that changes every day. I just want to be able to *add* values to the lookup column, not clear and re-set.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37dc3599-13ed-4048-b9eb-98e6f42efc3d/powershell-update-sharepoint-multiple-value-lookup-column?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: I don't want to have to open the csv file to look at the entries. I was hoping to automate the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to read the existing items and store them in a variable. For multi-values fields you'll want to SPFieldLookupValueCollection instead of SPFieldLookupValue. It's essentially an array of SPFieldLookupValue objects. Once you have the existing values, just call the field's .Add() method to add the new entry.

Here's some samples using SPFieldLookupValueCollection. They're in C# but you should be able to translate them to PowerShell easily enough:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.aspx